# Help doing a dynamic sort?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

- I have a notifications table which contains different types of notifications for different events.
- Inside the table is a `notifications_type:string` column that contains the type of notification, i.e. "foo" or "bar" or "oof"
- I want the user to be able to select what notifications they want to display, so there are checkboxes below the result that correspond to `prefs_display_foo:boolean, prefs_display_bar:boolean`  in the User model.
- What is an elegant way for me to set the `:conditions` in the find to properly display the sorted results?  Also, currently I have it as a method in the User model, but how would I do it as a `has_many :notifications, :conditions => .....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

leave the has_many without any conditions and then create a named_scope to handle the preferences, this code is untested

```
class User
    has_many :notifications  

    def notification_preferences
        list = []
        list << 'Foo' if prefs_display_foo
        list << 'Bar' if prefs_display_bar    
        # etc...
        return list
    end
end

class Notification
    belongs_to :user

    named_scope :preferred,
        lambda { |preferences| {
            :conditions => ["notifications_type IN (?)", preferences]
            }
        }
end

# ...
user = User.find(1)
notifications = user.notifications.preferred(user.notification_preferences)
```

Comment: Awesome.  I'm a bit new to named scopes but I can combine them right?  Meaning, I have one more prefs_display_results:integer for how many results they want, so if i add another scope called "limit" can I use something like <code>notifications = user.notifications.preferred(user.notification_preferences).limit(user.prefs_display_results)</code>

Comment: yeah, you can chain named_scopes (limit might be reserved word, not sure)

Comment: Nevermind... looking at it I'll just expand the lambda query and array

Comment: Thanks again house I really appreciate it! :)